# Strreaming json Data into Bigquery using java.With out using a job to load data

Tags: java, json, google-bigquery

I am new to bigquery so i do not fully understand how to stream data to bigquery, this is my problem, I have jsonInString, mapped from object like this

```
    String customerJsonInString = mapper.writeValueAsString(customer);

   {
  "id": "1",
  "first_name": "John",
  "last_name": "Doe",
  "dob": "1968-01-22",
  "addresses": [
    {
      "status": "current",
      "address": "123 First Avenue",
      "city": "Seattle",
      "state": "WA",
      "zip": "11111",
      "numberOfYears": "1"
    },
    {
      "status": "previous",
      "address": "456 Main Street",
      "city": "Portland",
      "state": "OR",
      "zip": "22222",
      "numberOfYears": "5"
    }
  ]
}
```

the table has been created with the correct schema.
now i want to stream this data into bigquery (insert row),i am using the example that is on (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery#bigquery-stream-data-java) to adapt it to mine, this is what i tried,

```
TableId tableId = TableId.of(DATASET_NAME,TABLE_NAME);
        Map<String, Object> recordsContent = new HashMap<>();
        recordsContent.put("Customer", customerJsonInString);
        InsertAllResponse response = bigquery.insertAll(InsertAllRequest.newBuilder(tableId)
                        .addRow("rowId", recordsContent)
                        .build());
        if (response.hasErrors()) {
            for (Entry<Long, List<BigQueryError>> entry : response.getInsertErrors().entrySet()) {
            }
        }
```

Comment: I'm guessing the schema of the table is "id, first_name, last_name, ..." instead of "customer"? In that case you'll need to set the fields one by one instead of as a whole json string, e.g. "recordsContent.put("id", 1)".

Comment: In addition, check the [example with comments](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-java/blob/master/google-cloud-examples/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/examples/bigquery/snippets/BigQuerySnippets.java#L382)

Comment: @HuaZhang can you please add your solution as a proper SO answer? The community would benefit through various features answers have and you'll benefit from the fame :) thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the schema of the table is `id, first_name, last_name, ...` instead of `customer`? In that case you'll need to set the fields one by one instead of as a whole json string, e.g. `recordsContent.put("id", 1)`.
Check the [example with comments](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-java/blob/master/google-cloud-examples/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/examples/bigquery/snippets/BigQuerySnippets.java#L382).